# Where is apxs on macOS Mojave?

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, macos-mojave

I recently bought a new Mac because the old one died. I installed everything except "System Files" from the old disk. Now I find I do not have `apxs` on my new computer. It was present at `/usr/sbin/apxs` on the old computer but not on the new one.

Is this a change made by Apple or is there something wrong with my installation?

How can I get it back? I don't use Homebrew at present and it seems a little excessive to install that just to get one thing.

Comment: I went to the city today (it's 80 miles/130 kilometres away) and checked on a Mac in the local Apple agent. apxs wasn't on it either so it's not a problem with my installation.